# Is memcached guaranteed to return value immediately after set?

Tags: memcached

Can I rely on fact that memcached will always return value for some key if it is set? And if it was just set? Even under heavy load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memcached will always return a value after it is set in memcached. The exception is if the value gets evicted in order to make room for another value or if the value expires.